# Codeigniter: Email sending works fine, but no emails received

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm new with emails in codeigniter

My controler:

```
class Email extends CI_Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index()
  {
    $config = array('protocol' => 'smpt',
                    'smtp_host' => 'belphegor.in-hell.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' => 'bla@blabla.com',
                    'smtp_pass' => 'blabla',
                    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('bla@blabla.com', 'My Blabla');
    $this->email->to('apa@yahoo.com');
    $this->email->subject('Just test');
    $this->email->message('qwe adlw is alqopl slaod');

    if ($this->email->send()) {
      echo "email send";
    } else {
      show_error($this->email->debugger());
    }

  }
}
```

when I run the code it show "email send", but when I check the server outgoing email is never existed. And when I login to my yahoo (apa@yahoo.com) is no email in. How I can fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your connection information (user, password, port, etc.) is correct? Also, try sending an email to a dump email like `mailinator.com` to test as those have no spam filter whatsoever.

Comment: Is `'protocol' => 'smpt'` a typo? Should be smtp. send() should be returning an error if it's an invalid protocol.

Comment: @Samutz nah, I wonder too, the result is not given error. Even typo

Comment: Codeigniter has a debugger for emails. Depends on which version you're using. This might help: `echo $this->email->print_debugger();`

Comment: OK everybody, I just refresh the page several time, and I got the email. I think there is trouble in the server past ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake on the config array on protocol key.

Try to change from:

```
 $config = array('protocol' => 'smpt',
                'smtp_host' => 'belphegor.in-hell.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'bla@blabla.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'blabla',
                );
```

to :

```
 $config = array('protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'belphegor.in-hell.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' => 'bla@blabla.com',
                    'smtp_pass' => 'blabla',
                    );
```

Comment: yes, I dont know even typo the server said success. Amazed. Although, the email did not send actually